# Meaning of essay question-

Tags: grammar

I was given this essay:

**

> ENUMERATE MAJOR BARRIERS TO QUALITATIVE EDUCATION IN NIGERIA

**

I have two questions:

1. How do you `enumerate` the points
2. By '**BARRIERS TO QUALITATIVE EDUCATION**' to they mean barriers to education itself or barriers to the quality of education?

Thanks

Comment: 1) First point, 2) second point, 3) third point ...  As to "qualitative education", that is a bit of jargon that would have to be interpreted by the jargon masters, but look up the definition of "qualitative" for some hints.

Comment: @HotLicks What was that supposed to mean?

Comment: I skim read and it took me a moment to realise there was anything wrong with 'qualitative'. I automatically read it in opposition to 'quantitative', ie. improving the quality of the education rather than the quantity. 'Enumerate' would normally mean to count as in a list, but given the essay character of the task, I expect they want you to give explanations too.

Answer (score 2):

*Literally*, the task name (which doesn't look a perfect set of words) suggests that the author should *write an enumerated list* (= enumerate) of **main reasons** (called 'major barriers' there),  **why it's hard to get** a good (qualitative = related to quality, as opposed to quantity) education in Nigeria. However, one can guess that it can be actually about more detailed description of such reasons (barriers - like social barriers or other major negative reasons), since it's an essay, usually written in a free form. So it's not about *any* education, it's about **good (quality) education** which is hard to get.

Comment: You seem to be tacitly assuming not only that the title intended "related to quality" to mean "good", but that the intention was reasonable.  The point's at least worth mentioning,.

Comment: I only tried to show _how_ the word 'qualitative' could appear in the task title: it has the same root as 'quality' (in 'quality education' which is OK).

Answer (score 2):

As HotLicks says in the comments, *enumerate* has a simple dictionary definition. The first barrier is teachers who do too little work for the salary they are paid, the second is shortage of resources, the third is corruption or 'dash'...

*Qualitative education* is not a normal phrase, and you need to check your textbook or equivalent to determine what was intended. In normal English it would mean 'education in determining quality' (which itself needs further clarification), but the essay-setter may have meant 'high-quality education', in which case you must use your own judgment as to whether to include as one of the barriers "educators who use words like *qualitative* without knowing what they mean".